# How can I display object content without specifying the attributes?

Tags: javascript

How can I display object content without specifying the attributes ? (The object here is used as associative array)

```
alert(result[0].name);
alert(result[0].surname);
```

I actually would like to not have to write "name" and "surname", but display all the content (keys & values)

thanks

Comment: It's an `Object` not an `associative array`, the latter one **is ordered** but objects are not..

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel So, you are saying there is not way to get all objects attributes and values ? Or to convert such object to an associative array ?

Comment: No, I just said that there are not associative arrays in JavaScript. If you want to display all the attributes, most `console.log` implementations will do that for you (if in doubt try `console.dir`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. (it uses for each loop):

```
var arr=[];
arr[0] = 'Test1';
arr['SomeKey'] = 'Test2';
for(var o in arr)
{
    var val = arr[o];
    alert("Key is: " + o);
    alert("Value is: " + val);
    for(var b in val)
    {
        alert("Inner Key is: " + b);
        alert("Inner Value is: " + val[b]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Both `o` and `b` leak into the global scope... and you too are missing `hasOwnProperty` :)

Answer (score 1):

Maby this will help you:

```
for (var item in result[0]) {
    var key=item;
    var val=b[item];
    alert('b['+key+']='+val);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Don't forget to use `hasOwnProperty`, otherwise this will also list stuff that's on the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as a clarification for the other answers:

```
result[0].name
```

is the same as

```
result[0]["name"]
```

However,

```
result[0][name]
```

would use whatever the current value of `name` is. E.g.

```
var name = "surname";
if (result[0][name] == result[0].surname)  // this is true
```